# IPageViewModel doesn't update my view

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel

So, first let me introduce my app.

I have MainWindowViewModel which control my 2 ViewModels:
- overviewviewmodel
- configureviewmodel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The current view.
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;

    /// <summary>
    /// Static instance of one of the ViewModels.
    /// </summary>
    public readonly static OverviewWindowViewModel _overviewviewmodel = new OverviewWindowViewModel();

    /// <summary>
    /// Static instance of one of the ViewModels.
    /// </summary>
    public readonly static ConfigurationWindowViewModel _configurationviewmodel = new ConfigurationWindowViewModel();

    /// <summary>
    /// The CurrentView property.  The setter is private since only this 
    /// class can change the view via a command.  If the View is changed,
    /// we need to raise a property changed event.
    /// </summary>

    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_currentViewModel == value)
                return;
            _currentViewModel = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Simple property to hold the 'OverviewViewCommand' - when executed
    /// it will change the current view to the 'Overview'
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand OverviewViewCommand { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Simple property to hold the 'ConfigurationViewCommand' - when executed
    /// it will change the current view to the 'Configuration'
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand ConfigurationViewCommand { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor.  We set the initial view-model to 'OverviewViewCommand'.
    /// We also associate the commands with their execution actions.
    /// </summary>
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = _overviewviewmodel;

        _overviewviewmodel.SwitchViewModel2Request += NavigateToView2;

        _configurationviewmodel.SwitchViewModel1Request += NavigateToView1;

        /*OverviewViewCommand = new RelayCommand(param => ExecuteOverviewViewCommand());
        ConfigurationViewCommand = new RelayCommand(param => ExecuteConfigurationViewCommand());*/
    }

    private void NavigateToView2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentViewModel = _configurationviewmodel;

    }

    private void NavigateToView1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentViewModel = _overviewviewmodel;
    }
}
```

Switch works very nice between two usercontrols. In "configurationviewmodel" I have also defined IPageViewModel for 12 buttons:

```
private ICommand _changePageCommand;
private List<IPageViewModel> _pageViewModels;
...
PageViewModels.Add(Buttons[0]);
PageViewModels.Add(Buttons[1]);
PageViewModels.Add(Buttons[2]);
PageViewModels.Add(Buttons[3]);
PageViewModels.Add(Buttons[4]);
PageViewModels.Add(Buttons[5]);
PageViewModels.Add(Buttons[6]);
PageViewModels.Add(Buttons[7]);
PageViewModels.Add(Buttons[8]);
PageViewModels.Add(Buttons[9]);
PageViewModels.Add(Buttons[10]);
PageViewModels.Add(Buttons[11]);

CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels[0];

private IPageViewModel _currentPageViewModel;
public IPageViewModel CurrentPageViewModel
{
   get
   {
      return _currentPageViewModel;
   }
   set
   {
      if (_currentPageViewModel != value)
      {
         _currentPageViewModel = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentPageViewModel");
      }
   }
}

private void ChangeViewModel(IPageViewModel viewModel)
{
   if (!PageViewModels.Contains(viewModel))
   PageViewModels.Add(viewModel);
   CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels
   .FirstOrDefault(vm => vm == viewModel);
}
```

My problems is that when button two is pressed, CurrentPageViewModel must change to PageViewModels[1], but that doesn't happen (it always stays on PageViewModels[0]). I know that my code before works, because in an old version I don't have two UserControls, but two different windows. So before in window "Configurationviewmodel" works like a charm, now in usercontrol "Configurationviewmodel" doesn't work.

Maybe I give enough code to understand my problem, if not please ask.

Comment: Does the line `PageViewModels.FirstOrDefault(vm => vm == viewModel);` returns correct viewModel? Also, what is the requirement to have this. You can directly set the `CurrentPageViewModel = viewModel'.

Comment: Doenst come to this line when debuging :S

Answer (score 0):

Since you are alreday making sure that the view model is contained within the PageViewModels collection, why not write:

```
private void ChangeViewModel(IPageViewModel viewModel)
{
    // If the view model is not in the collection, it is added.
    if (!PageViewModels.Contains(viewModel))
        PageViewModels.Add(viewModel);

    // So we can just assign the view mdoel here, since we know for sure
    // it is in the collection.
    CurrentPageViewModel = viewModel;
}
```

Also, have you tried vm.Equals(viewModel) for comparing the references?